# Handling connection with imaplib while using context manager

Tags: python, email, imap

I am trying to connect to mail server using python's `imaplib` . Here is how my code currently stands:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_connection(username: str, password: str, host=GMAIL_IMAP_HOST, port=GMAIL_IMAP_PORT):
    '''
    ARGS:
        username: User username
        password: User Password
        host: IMAP server address
        post: IMAP port

    Connect to IMAP server and close connection
    '''

    conn = None

    try:
        conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host, port)
        conn.login(username, password)
        response, _ = conn.select('INBOX')

        if response != 'OK':
            raise MyException('An error occurred authenticating - {}'.format(response))

        yield conn
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()   # <- Check if mailbox is selected
            conn.logout()  # <- Check if logged in
```

How can I check if the user is authenticated and if a mailbox is selected?